# X-editable with select2 and Ember.js

Tags: javascript, x-editable

I'm trying to use x-editable with select2 in an Ember.js application.

I created the following editable element:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="input-xlarge editable" data-url="children" multiple="multiple" data-pk="1">Test parent</a>
```

And used this JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

    $('.editable').editable({
        type: 'select2',

        select2: {
            placeholder: "Search for a parent...",
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            multiple: true,
            ajax: {
                url: 'http://localhost:8001/api/parents',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return { q: term }; // search term
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    return {results: data};
                }
            },
            formatResult: function(result) {
                return result.first_name + ' ' + result.last_name;
            },
            formatSelection: function(selection) {
                return selection.first_name + ' ' + selection.last_name;
            }
        },

        // Used for sending JSON instead of form data
        params: function(params) {
            return JSON.stringify(params);
        }
    });
});
```

When I click `Test child` the ajax spinner appears and the following error in console is shown: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null`

It refers to this:

```
$.fn.select2.defaults = {
    ...
    id: function (e) { return e.id; },
    ...
}
```

What could I be doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible you're dealing with a jQuery issue? I was just looking at x-editable and noticed that it's not supporting jQuery 1.9.x whereas that is the only jQuery version that EmberJS supports. Anyway, it was just a flier. Good luck getting to an answer.

Comment: Where did you read that x-editable doesn't support jQuery 1.9? I can't find it.

Comment: It was on their GitHub issues page. They discussed at least a partial work-around too but I am secretly hoping that Ember will support 2.x when it get's officially released (not that waiting is ever a good solution). Let me see if I can find the URL.

Comment: Well here's the link I was referring to: https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/pull/142

Answer (score 0):

Are you tapping into the X-Editable’s `success` method?

Here's an interesting article on how a company implemented X-Editable into an Ember app: http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2014/11/12/using-xeditable-with-ember/